# Ionic app runs on browser and ios but not on android, the connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file ///android_asset/www/index.html) on android

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

My ionic app was earlier working on all platforms i.e android and ios and also on browser with ionic serve.

But after a recent update when I tried adding android platform, i am building the app without issues but when I run the app on simulator or real device, it just shows a blank screen after the splash screen.

On emulator, the it shows a message as the connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file ///android_asset/www/index.html)

However the same app is running successfully without any issues on ios device, ios simulator and ionic serve.

Have tried few solutions listed online such as,

1. `<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />`
2. android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" on androidmanifest.xml
3. 

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <network-security-config>
            <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
                <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
                <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
            </domain-config>
        </network-security-config>
```

on network_security_config.xml where example.com was replaced by my domain.

But all of the above solutions did not work.

At first I thought it was due to cordova-android@9 version and tried switching back to previous versions but still no luck.

Here is my ionic info

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.13.1 (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.5.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.29
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.29
@angular/cli                  : 8.3.29
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.2

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
Cordova Platforms : android 9.0.0
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 19 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res (update available: 0.15.3) : 0.15.1
native-run                             : 1.3.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/rameshramgopal/Library/Android/sdk)
ios-deploy        : 1.11.3
ios-sim           : 8.0.2
NodeJS            : v15.6.0 (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/15.6.0/bin/node)
npm               : 7.7.6
OS                : macOS Big Sur
Xcode             : Xcode 12.3 Build version 12C33

Here is my package.json

```
    {
      "name": "woocommerce",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "author": "Ionic Framework",
      "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
        "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.26.0",
        "@ionic-native/app-minimize": "^5.21.5",
        "@ionic-native/app-rate": "^5.21.5",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/crop": "^5.21.6",
        "@ionic-native/email-composer": "^5.21.5",
        "@ionic-native/facebook": "^5.23.0",
        "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.21.6",
        "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.26.0",
        "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^5.24.0",
        "@ionic-native/http": "^5.21.5",
        "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^5.23.0",
        "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.23.0",
        "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "^5.26.0",
        "@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "^5.26.0",
        "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^5.23.0",
        "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^5.21.5",
        "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.21.5",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.21.5",
        "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
        "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^2.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^2.4.1",
        "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-appminimize": "^1.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-apprate": "^1.5.0",
        "cordova-plugin-crop": "^0.4.0",
        "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-email-composer": "^0.9.2",
        "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^6.4.0",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
        "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "8.4.0",
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^3.4.1",
        "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
        "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": "^2.3.0",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
        "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "git+https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/ImagePicker.git",
        "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.6.4",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^5.0.0",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
        "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.8.3",
        "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
        "tslib": "^1.9.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.20",
        "@angular/cli": "~8.3.23",
        "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
        "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
        "cordova-android": "^9.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "^4.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.15.0",
        "typescript": "~3.4.3"
      },
      "description": "An Ionic project",
      "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
          "cordova-plugin-email-composer": {},
          "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
          "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {},
          "cordova-plugin-apprate": {},
          "cordova-plugin-appminimize": {},
          "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
          "cordova-plugin-device": {},
          "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
          "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
          "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
          "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {},
          "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
          "cordova-plugin-crop": {},
          "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
          "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": {
            "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This will allow you to add product images",
            "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V7_VERSION": "27.+"
          },
          "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
          "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
          "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
            "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "com.googleusercontent.apps.806565206717-kmpd2cgn3prfe3e7gufh1uaq4r0sp98a",
            "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "15.0.1"
          },
          "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
            "APP_ID": "691375698089216",
            "APP_NAME": "Quick Order",
            "FACEBOOK_HYBRID_APP_EVENTS": "false",
            "FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION": "5.13.0"
          },
          "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
          "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
          "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {
            "PLAY_SERVICES_LOCATION_VERSION": "16.+"
          },
          "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {
            "LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION": "Use geocoder service"
          },
          "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
          "android"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Can anyone help me with the issue ?

Comment: Can you provide details on any errors that are appearing? What cordova/ionic command are you running? When you say "after a recent update", do you mean just updating some code, or updating versions?

Answer (score 0):

The persisting white screen appears when there is a build/compile error. Make sure to serve locally (browser) to check for errors first. Then connect your device via USB and use your computer's chrome inspect tool (chrome://inspect/#devices) to inspect for issues on your installed version. In case the `file ///android_asset/www/index.html` issue is unrelated, you will likely find it here. If you've done a recent update, it could be a dependency issue or something related.

You may also try `ionic cordova run android` instead of serving, in case there is an issue serving. Your mentioned network error could be CORS related, but I'm inclined to say maybe not.

If you can update your question to include the errors you're receiving, as well as the command, that'll help narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

Commonly, it is because on load time, it can’t reach the index.html file. Be sure that inside the android platform exists the www folder and, you should check that the FileSystem path in your Android App stills the same and any plugin has overwritted this path.

In addition probably should uninstall all the plugins and start a try/error process installing one by one , only to be sure that any plugin is not working properly.